# Default view for all routing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm starting with laravel. Now have created an admin Panel design. 
I want to display one view (menu in the left side for admin Panel) in default for all routings started on /admin

Then load the content of the container depending on the route. 
Do I have to set in all routes my view for left side or I can set it "globally" for all routes?

Laravel version I'm using is 5.7

Comment: I think that what you're looking for is a layout. Look at [the docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#defining-a-layout)

Answer (score 0):

You have just to create a layout for the admin, and all controller related to admin action will render view which extend the `admin` layout which you have define.

The layout file `admin.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <!-- use the css to style this element on the left -->
            <ul>
                <li>Your Menu code goes here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Here is where all content related to each route will be rendered -->
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you have a Controller which allow you to Edit Post you can render a view `admin/edit.blade.php`  which is define like this

```
@extends('admin.blade.php')

@section('content')
    Content to be display related to each route goes here
@endsection
```

The content which is wrap within the `@section('content')` will be render in the `admin.blade.php` which is the **admin layout** in the the container which wrap the `@yield('content`)`